# jQuery Slider in IE

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery-slider

I'm using a page with lot's of jquery sliders. Everything works fine in Chrome, Firefox, Safari, ...
But sometimes it doesn't work in Internet Explorer. And with sometimes I mean that it's really random. It's really strange.
Most of the time I get all of the sliders, sometimes I get none and sometimes a get some of the sliders.

It's an ASP.NET MVC 3 project and I'm using one view with multiple EditorTemplates.
There is jquery code inside the View and inside the Editor Templates.
(I'm just mentioning this to see if this could be a problem)

Has anyone seen this behavior before?

**EDIT**

Here's my code.

My View:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".guideSlider").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            disabled: true,
            animate: true
        });
        $(".average").slider({
            range: "min",
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 0.1,
            animate: true,
            disabled: true
        });
        var current = 0;
        var currentPage = 1;
        $(".next").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            if (submitForm(currentPage)) {
                currentPage++;
                current += 600;
                $('#wrapper').animate({
                    scrollLeft: current
                }, 1000);
            }
            return false;
        });

        $("#toOpenQuestions").click(function (e) {
            if (!submitForm(currentPage)) {
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        });

        $(".previous").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            currentPage--;
            current -= 600;
            $('#wrapper').animate({
                scrollLeft: current
            }, 1000);
            return false;
        });
        $(".matrixItem .slider").bind("slidestop", function () {
            var competenceId = $(this).parents("div[id$=competence]").attr("id");
            setAverage(competenceId);
        });
        $("form").submit(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize()
            });
            return false;
        });
    });

    function setAverage(competenceId) {
        var counter = 0;
        var value = 0;
        $("#" + competenceId + " div.matrixItem div.slider").each(function () {
            var itemValue = $(this).slider("value");
            if (itemValue > 0) {
                counter++;
                value += itemValue;
            }
        });
        if (counter > 0)
            value = value / counter;
        $("#" + competenceId + " div.ui-state-active div.average").slider("value", value);
    }

    function submitForm(currentPage) {
        var valid = true;
        $("#page" + currentPage + " .competenceWrapper").each(function () {
            var counter = 0;
            $(this).children("div.matrixItem").children("div.slider").each(function () {
                var itemValue = $(this).slider("value");
                if (itemValue > 0) {
                    counter++;
                }
            });
            if (counter < 2) valid = false;
        });
        if (valid)
            $("#matrixForm").submit();
        else
            alert("You have to provide a score for at least 2 items per Competence");

        return valid;
    }

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .ui-slider-handle
    {
        z-index: 101 !important;
    }
</style>
<div class="myVdp">
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mask">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Matrix", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "matrixForm" }))
            {
                @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RequestId)
                @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Pages)
            }
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div[id$=competence]").each(function () {
            var competenceId = $(this).attr("id");
            setAverage(competenceId);
        });
    });
</script>
```

MatrixPage EditorTemplate

```
    @{ 
    string pageId = "page" + Model.PageNumber;
    string progressBarId = "progressBar" + Model.PageNumber;
    string guideClass = (Model.PageNumber % 2 == 0) ? "normal" : "flipBg";
}
<div id="@pageId" class="item">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var value = ((@Model.PageNumber-1)/@ViewBag.TotalPages)*100;
            $("#@progressBarId").progressbar({ value: value });
        });     
    </script>
    <div id="guideBgColor" class="@guideClass">
        <div id="guideBgImage" class="@guideClass">
            <div id="guide">
                <span id="zero">No score</span> <span id="one">High need for improvement</span>
                <span id="seven">Being a grandmaster</span>
                <div class="sliderBackground">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="slider guideSlider">
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="score">
                <li>0</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li class="lastItem">7</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    @{
        <div class="innerPage">
            @Html.EditorFor(m => m.MatrixCompetences)
        </div>
        <div class="progressbar" id="@progressBarId">
        </div>
        if (Model.PageNumber > 1)
        {
            string previousPage = "page" + (Model.PageNumber - 1);
        <a href="#@previousPage" class="previous">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Left.png")" alt="previous" /></a>
        }

        if (Model.PageNumber < ViewBag.TotalPages)
        {
            string nextPage = "page" + (Model.PageNumber + 1);
        <a href="#@nextPage" class="next">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/right.png")" alt="next" /></a>
        }
        else
        {
        <a href="@Url.Action("MatrixOpenQuestions", "Home", new { requestId = @ViewBag.requestId })" id="toOpenQuestions">
            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Images/right.png")" alt="next" /></a>
        }
    }
</div>
```

MatrixCompetence EditorTemplate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#@Model.CompetenceId.ToString()_competence .slider .ui-slider-range").css("background", "@Model.ColorHex");
        $("#@Model.CompetenceId.ToString()_competence .slider .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "@Model.ColorHex");
    });                     
</script>
<div id="@Model.CompetenceId.ToString()_competence" class="competenceWrapper">
    <div class="ui-state-active competence">
        <div class="competenceText">@Model.Text</div>
        <div class="slider average">
        </div>
    </div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.MatrixItems)
</div>
```

MatrixItem EditorTemplate

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#@Model.ItemId").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: @Model.Score,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#@Model.ItemId  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "@Model.ColorHex");
        $("#@Model.ItemId  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "@Model.ColorHex");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        @Model.Text</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="@Model.ItemId" class="slider">
    </div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m=>Model.ItemId)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => Model.Score)
</div>
```

**EDIT**

Here's a screenshot. You can see that a few sliders are generated, but after 3 it suddendly doesn't work.
[image: screenshot]

After pressing F5, it shows this. That should be the case from the start.

[image: after refresh]

This is one page of the "live" code.

```
<div id="page1" class="item">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var value = ((1-1)/11)*100;
            $("#progressBar1").progressbar({ value: value });
        });     
    </script>
    <div id="guideBgColor" class="flipBg">
        <div id="guideBgImage" class="flipBg">
            <div id="guide">
                <span id="zero">No score</span> <span id="one">High need for improvement</span>
                <span id="seven">Being a grandmaster</span>
                <div class="sliderBackground">
                    &nbsp;</div>
                <div class="slider guideSlider">
                </div>
            </div>
            <ul id="score">
                <li>0</li>
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
                <li>4</li>
                <li>5</li>
                <li>6</li>
                <li class="lastItem">7</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="innerPage">
            <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#1_competence .slider .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#1_competence .slider .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });                     
</script>
<div id="1_competence" class="competenceWrapper">
    <div class="ui-state-active competence">
        <div class="competenceText">Structured</div>
        <div class="slider average">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#1").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#1  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#1  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He is organised and works in a structured manner.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="1" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_0__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[0].ItemId" type="hidden" value="1" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_0__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[0].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#2").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#2  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#2  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He sets priorities and deadlines.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="2" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_1__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[1].ItemId" type="hidden" value="2" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_1__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[1].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#3").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#3  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#3  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He plans well in advance.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="3" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_2__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[2].ItemId" type="hidden" value="3" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_2__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[2].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#4").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#4  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#4  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He arrives on time.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="4" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_3__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[3].ItemId" type="hidden" value="4" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_0__MatrixItems_3__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[0].MatrixItems[3].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#2_competence .slider .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#2_competence .slider .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });                     
</script>
<div id="2_competence" class="competenceWrapper">
    <div class="ui-state-active competence">
        <div class="competenceText">Result Oriented</div>
        <div class="slider average">
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#5").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#5  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#5  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He sets achievable goals/priorities.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="5" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_0__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[0].ItemId" type="hidden" value="5" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_0__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[0].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#6").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#6  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#6  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He focuses on the result.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="6" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_1__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[1].ItemId" type="hidden" value="6" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_1__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[1].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#7").slider({
            range: "min",
            value: 0,
            min: 0,
            max: 7,
            step: 1,
            animate: true,
            slide: function(event,ui) {
                $(this).siblings("input[id$=Score]").val(ui.value);
            }
        });
        $("#7  .ui-slider-range").css("background", "#004c97");
        $("#7  .ui-slider-handle").css("border-color", "#004c97");
    });
</script>
<div class="matrixItem">
    <div class="itemText">
        He meets his deadlines.</div>
    <div class="sliderBackground">
        &nbsp;</div>
    <div id="7" class="slider">
    </div>
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field ItemId must be a number." data-val-required="The ItemId field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_2__ItemId" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[2].ItemId" type="hidden" value="7" />
    <input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Score must be a number." data-val-required="The Score field is required." id="Pages_0__MatrixCompetences_1__MatrixItems_2__Score" name="Pages[0].MatrixCompetences[1].MatrixItems[2].Score" type="hidden" value="0" />
</div>

</div>

        </div>
        <div class="progressbar" id="progressBar1">
        </div>
```

Hopefully you guys can help me out. Because I don't know what to try anymore.

Kind Regards
Tim

Comment: show the generated code, I think it would be more helpful. Also you can try removing the sliders and test them 1 by 1, maybe one of them is causing the rest to break. For example, test the first 1, then add the second and so on and see when it starts to break. Do you get errors in IE?

Comment: I don't get any errors. The problem is that it works in most cases. But sometimes it fails. And pressing F5 solves the issue.

Comment: I'm using IE 9. But could be in other versions as well

Comment: Not sure if this is the cause, but I'd put your functions (setAverage, submitForm) either at the very top of the $(document).ready() function, or before it rather than after it. I've had instances in Firefox where functions have failed to fire if they weren't defined before they were called... If possible, I'd also put all the slider functions into a single $(document).ready() function.

Comment: @MassivePenguin I'll try to put the functions on top. But it's a bit to test since it seems to be random. :-)

Comment: I made some changes to get all the slider functions at the top. But no luck. Still having problems. I also validated the HTML to be sure that it's not causing issues. Bet even with some cleanup there, I can't seem to get it to work every time. Any other suggestions are more then welcome. :-)

Comment: Does anybody have an idea? Because it's getting a bit urgent.